# which text editor allows you to double click to highligh entire row

Tags: text, editor

I am after a text editor that I can click on a line twice and it highlights and selects the entire line so that I can easily press ctrl+c to copy and paste the whole line quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++ if you triple click it will select whole line

also here are some useful tips for productivity in notepad++ http://a4apphack.com/featured/tricks-with-notepad

Comment: You can also duplicate the line with ctrl-d, then move it up or down with ctrl-shift-up/-down, if you want the duplicate close by.  All the shortcuts are in the Settings menu, under Shortcup Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

- Notepad
- Notepad2
- SublimeText
- Firefox
- Notepad++

I often use `Home`+`End` or `End`+`Home` buttons then `Ctrl`+`C` to copy text per/row.